# Filtering a Datatable using Select()

Tags: c#, vb.net, datatable

I have a DataTable (dt) as

```
 StartDate    EndDate    Price
  1              3          10
  4              6          12
  7              10          16
  11             15          20
```

I want to  filter the Values from dates between fromdate= 2 and todate=8.

so i am expecting the result to be

```
 StartDate         EndDate     Price
      1              3          10
      4              6          12
      7              10         16
```

I have used the vb Datatable Select as->

```
dt.Select("StartDate <= #" & fromdate& "# And EndDate >= #" & todate& "#")
```

but i am not getting the result. Can u please suggest me..

Comment: Shouldn't it be `startDate >= ... and EndDate <= ... `? Also, use `'` (apostrophe) in place of `#`.

Comment: Expected result do not match for `dates between fromdate= 2 and todate=8`

Comment: Your expected result doesn't match your conditions, as `4` and `7` are greater than `2`, also the endate doesn't match as `3` and `6` are lesser than `8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should be like that:

```
dt.Select("StartDate <= #" & todate & "# And EndDate >= #" & fromdate & "#")
```

to find records that overlap with your range.

Comment: `todate` and `fromdate` are swapped.

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
dt.Select("StartDate >= " & fromdate & " And EndDate <= " & todate)
```

Two problems

1. Your operator were all wrong. You were taking startdate less than 2 and greater than 8 whereas it should be startdate greater than 2 and less than 8
2. Morever no need for # assuming that columns are of integer type.

Comment: That won't work. It won't return the first record as 1 >= 2 is not true.

Comment: Well @Pravin Kumars expected result doesn't match his conditions at all.

Comment: Any alternates @Tafari

Comment: @Tafari: That's what I said to OP.

Comment: @Pravin Kumar I believe Szymon has provided you with the right conditions.

Answer (score -1):

Use the DateDiff function, my friend